# ember update failed: handlebars incompatibility

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I recently updated to the last version of ember-rails gem, and at page load, it gives:

```
Assertion failed: Ember Handlebars requires Handlebars version 1.0.0, COMPILER_REVISION expected: 4, got: 3 - Please note: Builds of master may have other COMPILER_REVISION values.
```

these are my versions:

```
DEBUG: ------------------------------- application.js:34652
DEBUG: Ember.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.6 application.js:34652
DEBUG: Handlebars.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.4 application.js:34652
DEBUG: jQuery.VERSION : 1.10.0 application.js:34652
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

and these are my gems :

```
gem 'ember-rails'
gem 'ember-source', '1.0.0.rc6'
gem 'handlebars-source', '1.0.0.rc4'
```

I really don't know what to do, because searching the error they say these versions are compatible

I also tried another combination:

```
DEBUG: ------------------------------- application.js:34652
DEBUG: Ember.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.6 application.js:34652
DEBUG: Handlebars.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.4 application.js:34652
DEBUG: jQuery.VERSION : 1.10.0 application.js:34652
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

still with the same error. But note that in the gem page they give these 2 versions as compatible

Also removing gem handlebars-source from Gemfile gave no results

---

Solved clearing my tmp folder

Comment: Looks like rc.6.1 - http://builds.emberjs.com/ember-1.0.0-rc.6.1.js is compatible with handlebars-rc4

Comment: handlebars-source uses COMPILER_REVISION 3 which is not compatible with ember-source rc6.

Comment: ember-source gem is only available as 1.0.0.rc6.3 for RC6, installed it but it doesn't work. see question update